# SweetAlert2 with Autocomplete feature of JQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, sweetalert2

I would like to get jquery Autocomplete feature inside a sweetalert2 popup

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Get Users',
  html: '<input type="text" id="name" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Search name...">',

  showCancelButton: false,
  confirmButtonText: 'Next',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
   Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
  }
})

$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "John",
      "Jane",
      "Janos",
      "Lisa",
      "Rita"
    ];
    $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

How to achieve this?

It seems that the input "name" is not affected by the autocomplete call.

Comment: which version of sweetaleart you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery UI autocomplete menu is hiding behind the sweet alert modal. You can give a z-index with high value and it will show. Here is the updated code:-

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Get Users',
    html: '<input type="text" id="name" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Search name...">',

    showCancelButton: false,
    confirmButtonText: 'Next',
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
        Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
    }
})

$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "John",
        "Jane",
        "Janos",
        "Lisa",
        "Rita"
    ];
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete{
  z-index: 1111;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-dark@4/dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

There is **one warning in the console** that is because you are using **showLoaderOnConfirm: true** but you have not defined **preconfirm** in your function. You can see example of **showLoaderOnConfirm** and **preconfirm** on [sweetalert documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using sweetalert2 https://sweetalert2.github.io/ which seems different from what you linked.

Comment: with sweetalert2 we can also use input: 'text',
                            inputPlaceholder: 'Cerca Paziente ...',
                            inputAttributes: {
                                id: 'name',                      
                            },

Comment: @KROM No problem I have try with that version. And I know whats a problem, Let me update the code

Comment: Thank you for the update and indeed it works now. the warning has been also removed.